# Why after the death of a family member or a close relatives they won't pray till the 11th day ceremony?

Tags: rituals, death, garuda-purana

When my grandfather passed away, my family did not pray for 11 days till the 11th day ceremony. Also we were vegetarian during that period.

I asked my family but I did not get a convincing answer.

1. Why should we be vegetarian these days?
2. Why we should not pray these days?

Comment: The one who dies doesn't leave home till 10th day after death so you'll only pray for someone when they have departed which happens on the 11th day. [This question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13824/3872) might help.

Comment: Because that period is considered as Ashuchi a period of impurity.